# Python как проверить на отсутствие элементов в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [[['1', '2', '3'], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [['1', '2', '3'], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Существует ли более удобный способ задать условие на отсутствие в подсписках `[['1', '2', '3'], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]` или в `[['1', '2', '3'], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]` списков, у которых первый элемент соответствует определенному значению. А если хоть один из списков содержит такой элемент в индексе 0, то сделать определенное действие. Надеюсь понятно задал вопрос)) Сейчас я делаю это вот так, но такое кажется очень громоздким:

```
t1 = []
t2 = []
for i in a:
    count = 0
    for j in i:
        if j[0] == 1:
            t1.append(j[1])
            t2.append(j[2])
        else:
            count += 1           
    if count == len(i):
        t1.append(0)
        t2.append(0)          
print(t1)
print(t2)
```

То есть если вдруг в списке не встречается ни одного списка, у которого 1 элемент равен 1, то в финальный список нужно добавить 0

Comment: «А если хоть один из списков содержит такой элемент в индексе 0» (c) и `if count == len(i)` противоречат...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

насчет действий не скажу, проверить можно так:

```py
a = [[['1', '2', '3'], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], [['1', '2', '3'], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]

for lst in a:
  value = all(map(lambda x: x[0] != 1, lst))
```

т.е в списке не должно быть подсписков, которые бы начинались с 1, если я правильно все понял. в `value` будет `True` или `False`, что значит выполняется ли условие или нет(для каждого списка в `a`), осталось прикрутить сюда проверку `value`..